# Shortest-path algorithms used in Networkx: what about points not near nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, networkx, osmnx

I am new to Networkx, but am I right that Dijkstra's is the algorithm Networkx uses by default? From what I understand, Dijkstra's algorithm traces a shortest path between two nodes on a graph. What, then, should I do if I need to calculate the shortest path to or from a point that is near an edge on a graph, but not near a node? Are there any other algorithms used by Networkx that are better suited for this? Are there any that can, for example, find the nearest place on an edge to/from which to trace, rather than the nearest node? My network has only distance for a weight, and my point datasets will seldom have more than a few hundred points, in case this helps.

Comment: There is at least one more algorithm for weighted graphs. Re points: if it is not a node, it is foreign entity. Distance from it = min(distanceFromNode+chainage, distanceToNode+(edgeLength-chainage)), where chainage is length from start node to point projection on relevant (nearest) edge.

Comment: Is there any way to add a node onto an edge near a foreign-entity point?

Comment: Easily, if you know your gis software.